# Using guard-rspec without a spec directory

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

When I run `guard` with the following Guardfile

```
guard :rspec do
end
```

I get this error:

```
/home/pat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:
in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/pat/c/challenges/codeeval/working_experience/spec (LoadError)
```

Is it possible to use [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) without a `spec` directory? Maybe you have your code and test files in the same directory, or maybe your spec folder is named something else. Is there a workaround?

Comment: there is no good reason to have specs in a root directory. they should always be in a subfolder. but there are plenty of configuration options available, which one did you try? https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec

Comment: I see now that there's a `spec_paths` option that you can use if your specs are in a directory named something other than `specs`. Thanks.

Comment: The reason to have specs in the root directory is that it's slightly easier if you're dealing with just one spec file and one source file. It seems kind of silly to make subdirectories with just one file each in them. But in this case, it might be better just to run the tests manually rather than go to the trouble of setting up guard.